# Singleton property binding not updating when property manually set

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, singleton

I have a Singleton object called `AppContext` (which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`) with a `IsLogged` property inside.

```
public class AppContext : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private static AppContext instance;

    public AppContext() { }

    public static AppContext Instance {
        get => instance ?? (instance = new AppContext());
    }

    static bool _isLogged = true;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public bool IsLogged {
        get => _isLogged;
        set {
            _isLogged = value;
            Console.WriteLine("islogged = {0}", value);
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

I store a `StaticResource` in my `Application.Resources` which refers to `AppContext` in the file `App.xaml`:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <local:AppContext x:Key="AppContext"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

I have two different `Window`s in which there the same checkbox declaration:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Source={StaticResource AppContext}, Path=IsLogged}"/>
```

Here's my problem:

When I check/uncheck a checkbox on one of the two windows, it works well (the two checkboxes keep the same state).

But if I add a button which, on click, changes the state of `IsLogged`, the checkboxes are not updated.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    AppContext.Instance.IsLogged = !AppContext.Instance.IsLogged;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Diagnosis

The root of your problems is that your `AppContext` class isn't really a singleton - it has a public constructor which allows to create any number of instances. And that's exactly what happens - this code:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <local:AppContext x:Key="AppContext"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

creates a new instance rather than refers to the (intended) singleton instance - notice that there's no reference to `AppContext.Instance` property in this code. This newly created instance is shared between your windows (hence checking/unchecking works), but when you modify the `AppContext.Instance` object you actually modify different object than the one your checkboxes are bound to.

## Solution

In order to fix your code you should modify your bindings to use the `AppContext.Instance` as source:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Static local:AppContext.Instance}, Path=IsLogged}"/>
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep your bindings and have your singleton as a resource, you should modify the `"AppContext"` resource to refer to the `AppContext.Instance` property:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <x:Static x:Key="AppContext" MemberType="{x:Type local:AppContext}" Member="Instance" />
</Application.Resources>
```

Also, although it is not necessary to fix this issue, I'd recommend to make the `AppContext` constructor private, so that you follow the singleton pattern and don't accidentally create new instances.

Comment: Thank you very much that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I had an error with `<x:Static x:Key="AppContext" MemberType="{x:Type local:AppContext}" Member="Instance" />`. I changed this line by `<x:Static x:Key="AppContext" Member="local:AppContext.Instance" />`. Now it's fully working, thank you!

Comment: That's strange. Would you care to share some details about this error and what framework version are you working with?

Comment: I'm going to school now, would you mind if I do this later?

Comment: Whenever it suits you.

Comment: I've some time now... I had this error: `Cannot find the member "Instance" on the target type`. And I'm working with `.NET Framework 4.5.1`.

Comment: I've managed to reproduce this error - strangely enough it occurs on one machine, but does not on other. It seems to be some weird perk of the _XAML Designer_, because despite this error being shown in design-time it works properly in runtime. Didn't find any solution other than the one you mentioned.

Comment: Ok, yes it's strange. Thanks again for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my property `Instance` was creating a different instance from the `StaticResource` in my `App.xaml` file...

I ended up adding this to `App.xaml.cs`:

```
static AppContext _context;

public static AppContext Context { 
    get => _context ?? (_context = (AppContext) Current.Resources["AppContext"]);
}
```

And now I use this in the button:

```
App.Context.IsLogged = !App.Context.IsLogged;
```

With that, there is only one instance.

**But if you have a better way to do this, I'm interested :)**